# What makes a path finding heuristic Monotonic vs. Non-monotonic?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I am currently working on an algorithm that solves a path through the maze. So far I have implemented a Manhattan and Pythagorean Heuristic. I was wondering what makes a heuristic monotonic and how would one go about making a heuristic non-monotonic.

Comment: You could ask this on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the Manhattan distance monotonic when used as heuristic function?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/56730/is-the-manhattan-distance-monotonic-when-used-as-heuristic-function)

Comment: May I ask why you want to know how to make a heuristic *non-monotonic*? Or is it the opposite you're after: how to make a heuristic *monotonic*?

Answer (score 2):

A heuristic \$h\$ is monotonic when, in addition to being admissible (meaning the estimate is always equal or lesser to the actual minimum cost) the heuristic satisfies the relation:

$$h(x) <= d(x,y) + h(y)$$

fo all adjacent nodes \$x\$ and \$y\$, where \$d(x,y)\$ is the distance from node \$x\$ to node \$y\$.

More can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

**Update**: (thanks to [ilmari-karonen](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/9280/ilmari-karonen)):
An even better link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic):

*Consistent* (aka *monotonic) heuristics are usually preferred because as each node is reached, consistency guarantees that the path length to that point is equal to the minimal path-length from the start node. This means that a *closed-set* can be used to avoid expanding nodes more than once.

The most common use of an admissible but not consistent heuristic is when using a **bidirectional** A*; however in this instance each branch is self-consistent, and so it suffices to expand each node once from each branch.

Comment: ...or better yet, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: Comments being intended as temporary, I have incorporated your link in my answers. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest two improvements to this answer: how to make an admissible heuristic monotonic (using pathmax for example), and reason why we want heuristics to be monotonic.

Comment: *"is monotonic when, in addition to being admissible..."* - Usually the definition of 'consistent' is given to be just your `h(x) <= d(x,y) + h(y)` constraint, plus the constraint that `h(goal) = 0`.  Then the heuristic is provably admissible; this form is given because, when proving consistency, it's much easier to show that `h(goal) = 0` than it is to show that the heuristic is admissible :)